# Discord.py add multiple values with for loop to single embedfield

Tags: python, for-loop, discord.py

I am currently setting up a Musicbot using Lavalink. 
For my queue-function I want to use an  embed with two fields: One for the currently playing track and one for the enqueued tracks. 
Using a for-loop to grab information from the Lavalink Audiotrack objects:

```
embed.add_field(name="Currently playing",value=f"[{player.current.title}]({player.current.uri})")
for track in player.queue:
    embed.add_field(name="Enqueued Tracks",value=f"[{track.title}]({track.uri})",inline=False)
```

Which adds a [new field](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/808017365089648670/877976737424760912/unknown.png) every time a track is added to the enqueued tracks.
Is there a way to add values to a specific embed field or do I have to store the objects in a list to use them without the use of a for-loop. 
Just asking what the most efficient and easiest method would be here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on what your goal is- and I was unclear on this when writing my answer, so bear with me. If your goal is to create a new embed field for every single enqueued track as they come, store a referenced to the embed and just use the `.add_field()` method like you do.

That being said, if you're looking to have *one* field with a list of enqueued tracks, you might consider trying a generator like so.

```py
embed: discord.Embed = discord.Embed().add_field(
    name="Currently Playing",
    value=f"[{player.current.title}]({player.current.uri})"
)

embed.add_field(
    name="Enqueued Tracks",
    value='\n'.join([f"[{track.title}]({track.uri})" for track in player.queue]), 
    inline=False
)
```

What this in-line for loop does is create a list of strings formatted as `[title](url)`, joins them with newline characters (one track per line), and inserts them into the value of the field. You can expect this to look something like the following, before being joined with newline characters.

```py
["[title1](url1)", "[title2](url2)", "[title3](url3)"]
```

If you want to update the embed, you can go about that in two ways. Extract this code into its own method and pass *all tracks* including the new one into the method each time you need to update it (best in my opinion), or, since you know that it's the second field in the embed, you can access it at

```py
embed.fields[1].value = "New Value"
```

The choice is yours, good luck!

Comment: Thanks this was exactly what I was looking for!